# Trouble centering text and image

Tags: html, css

Im trying to style a div I need to be able to center both lines of text on top of each other with the image (`.hand`) next them on the right. I can not get this. I must not be understanding how to do this because I've looked up solutions but they are not working for me. Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/iamgonge/pen/MQvEWY?editors=1100

here is an image of what it should look like:[what section should look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vdrc.png)

here is my code:
HTML:

```
 <div class="events">
   <h1>You're Cool, We're Cool,</h1>
   <p class="moveit">come see us at a event near you.</p>
   <img class="hand"src="http://res.cloudinary.com/adamscloud/image/upload/v1518559592/hand_lco9ed.png">
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.events {
    background: #fbdd37;
  height: 150px;

}
.events h1{
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.moveit{
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.hand {
    width: 8%;
}
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using flexbox.

Enclose the `h1` and `p` in a div(`.text`) and then

add `display:flex;` in the `.events` container

also you will need to set the margin of `h1` and `p` since they have a default margin.

```
p,h1{  margin:10px 20px;  }
```

Please see the sample code below.

```css
.events {
  background: #fbdd37;
  height: 150px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.text{
  text-align:center;
}
.hand {
    width: 15%;
}

p,h1{
  margin:10px 20px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="events">
   <div class="text">
     <h1>You're Cool, We're Cool,</h1>
     <p class="moveit">
       come see us at a event near you.
     </p>
   </div>
   <img class="hand"src="http://res.cloudinary.com/adamscloud/image/upload/v1518559592/hand_lco9ed.png">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `events` and `moveit` into a container div:

```
<div class="events">
   <div id="container"> <!-- This div added -->
     <h1>You're Cool, We're Cool,</h1>
     <p class="moveit">come see us at a event near you.</p>
   </div>
   <img class="hand"src="http://res.cloudinary.com/adamscloud/image/upload/v1518559592/hand_lco9ed.png">
 </div>
```

And then the minimal CSS:

```
.events {
    background: #fbdd37;
  height: 150px;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%; 
}
.moveit{
    margin-top: 0;
}
#container{
text-align:center;  
  float:left; 
  margin-left:500px;
}
.hand {
  width: 8%;
  float:left;
  margin-left:50px;
}
```

This gets you close to your picture.  Of course, adjust the fonts, etc. for a closer match.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. It works mainly with inline-blocks and two wrapper DIVs, the inner one wrapping the two text elements, the outer one wrapping the inner wrapper and the image. that outer wrapper is centered with `text-align: center`, which works since it's an inline-block. The vertical centering is done the usualy way: `position: relative`, `top: 50%` and `transform: translateY(-50%)`:

```css
.events {
  background: #fbdd37;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.outer_wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.inner_wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
.events h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.moveit {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.hand {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="events">
  <div class="outer_wrap">
    <div class="inner_wrap">
      <h1>You're Cool, We're Cool,</h1>
      <p class="moveit">come see us at a event near you.</p>
    </div>
    <img class="hand" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/adamscloud/image/upload/v1518559592/hand_lco9ed.png">
  </div>

</div>
```

The same in a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQMqOw

Answer (score 0):

This should give you something close. I used flexbox. You would just need to style the font style, boldness, and etc.

--HTML--

```
 <div class="events">
    <div class="texts">
      <div class="first-line">
        <h1>You're Cool, We're Cool,</h1>
      </div>
    <div class="second-line">
       <h2 class="moveit">come see us at a event near you.</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img class="hand" 
   src="http://res.cloudinary.com/adamscloud/image/upload/
   v1518559592/hand_lco9ed.png"/>
  </div>
```

--CSS--

```
.events {
  background: #fbdd37;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hand {
  width: 10%;
  height: 40%;
  margin: 35px 20px;
}
```